# Get user-defined vibration duration

Tags: javascript, navigator, vibration

We can trigger vibration on supported devices like so:

```
navigator.vibrate(50);
```

But does the API support any access to user-defaults? In other words, is it possible to get the vibration duration from the OS? So when a user would normally press a button when using the device, get that vibration duration (if any)?

Comment: Sound unlikely. Each OS has its own setting for keypress vibrations, which are also configurable. I find it hard to believe you can pull this from the OS using javascript.

Comment: Addition to the comment above, also consider that every mobile device has its own setting too.

Comment: I am aware that each device has its own configuration, and that users can even change their settings. That's exactly why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible directly or indirectly.

Per [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/#security-and-privacy-considerations),

> Vibration API is not a source of data on its own and as such is not producing any data possible to consume on the Web.

Therefore, *no data* can be obtained via the vibration API directly.

However, the section also states

> [I]t is known that it can serve as a source of events for other APIs. In particular, it is known that certain sensors such as accelerometers or gyroscopes are prone to tiny imperfections during their manufacturing. As such, they provide a fingerprinting surface that can be exploited utilizing the vibration stimuli generated via the Vibration API.

So in theory, yes, you *could* obtain the actual duration by using the accelerators and/or gyroscopes and transforming the data appropriately.

However, there's another caveat: per [the WebIDL](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/#vibration-interface), a `VibratePattern` (defined as `number | number[]`) *must* be provided as an argument. As such, *you can't invoke vibration with the default*.

I personally doubt this will be converted to an optional parameter in a future version of the specification due to privacy considerations (this very much allows for fingerprinting).

Keep in mind, though, that not all platforms even support vibration, and will return `false` when called. It's also perfectly valid to refuse action (which will also return `false`)

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately, no, at least not in its current state (W3C Editor's Draft 27 June 2019)

You can read through the entire specification [here](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/); it is pretty short.

Unfortunately as you can see there is only a single method defined, `vibrate`, so this API certainly **will not let you get user-set defaults**.

And reading further into the [validate and normalize](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/#dfn-validate-and-normalize) section that talks about the pattern, it looks like **you cannot even *trigger* user defined-length patterns**, you have to be explicit about your timings.

It may be possible that a later Draft (or a separate "User preferences API") will add functionality like the one you need, but I personally doubt it (because of reasons mentioned in comments).